# Counting lines in a data file

Tags: c, feof

In this code snippet I try to count the number of rows contained in a file. The data are divided into seven columns and 421 rows. However, the total number outmput returns as 422, that is counted in more than one line. 
Why? 
How can I avoid this problem?

I know it's wrong to use instruction while (! Feof (inStr)), but I was asked explicitly to use it.

```
int valid = 0;

[...]

while(!feof(inStr)){
        fscanf(inStr," %c %f %f %f %f %f %d",&app1, &app2, &app3, &app4, &app5, &app6,&app7);
        valid++;
    }
    printf("%d",valid);
```

Comment: Use it immediately after the fscanf() call, not in the while expression.

Comment: Subtract one from the result:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to do the `feof` check immediately after you try to `fscanf`, but before you increment your row counter. Otherwise you will increment it for the `eof`.

```
while(1){
    fscanf(inStr," %c %f %f %f %f %f %d",&app1, &app2, &app3, &app4, &app5, &app6,&app7);
    if (feof(inStr)) break;
    valid++;
}
printf("%d",valid);
```

Of course, you could also do as Martin James suggested and subtract one from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop `while (!feof(...))`, it will not work as you expect since the EOF flag is not set until after you try to read from beyond the end of the file. Instead use e.g. `while (fscanf(...) == 7)` (in your specific case).

The problem with using `while (!feof(...))` is that it will loop *once to many* which is exactly the problem you have.